# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: Detected at node

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, collaborative-filtering

My idea is to train a collaborative filter model for arts. I'm trying to train my model like this:

```
def utils_plot_keras_training(training):
    metrics = [k for k in training.history.keys() if ("loss" not in k) and ("val" not in k)]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(15,3))

    ax[0].set(title="Training")
    ax11 = ax[0].twinx()
    ax[0].plot(training.history['loss'], color='black')
    ax[0].set_xlabel('Epochs')
    ax[0].set_ylabel('Loss', color='black')
    for metric in metrics:
        ax11.plot(training.history[metric], label=metric)
    ax11.set_ylabel("Score", color='steelblue')
    ax11.legend()

    ax[1].set(title="Validation")
    ax22 = ax[1].twinx()
    ax[1].plot(training.history['val_loss'], color='black')
    ax[1].set_xlabel('Epochs')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('Loss', color='black')
    for metric in metrics:
        ax22.plot(training.history['val_'+metric], label=metric)
    ax22.set_ylabel("Score", color="steelblue")
    plt.show()

training = model.fit(x=[train["user_id"], train["art_id"]], y=train["y"],
                         epochs=100, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, verbose=0, validation_split=0.3)
    model = training.model
    utils_plot_keras_training(training)
```

And getting next error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [30], in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 # train
> ----> 2 training = model.fit(x=[train["user_id"], train["art_id"]], y=train["y"],
> 3                      epochs=100, shuffle=True, verbose=0, validation_split=0.3)
> 4 model = training.model
> 5 utils_plot_keras_training(training)
>
> File
> ~\DataspellProjects\Arts\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67,
> in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
> 66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> ---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 68 finally:
> 69   del filtered_tb
>
> File
> ~\DataspellProjects\Arts\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54,
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
> 52 try:
> 53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
> ---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> 55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
> 56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 57   if name is not None:
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
>
> Detected at node 'CollaborativeFiltering/xusers_emb/embedding_lookup'
> defined at (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals) ........
>
> Node: 'CollaborativeFiltering/xusers_emb/embedding_lookup'
> indices[28,0] = 1000 is not in [0, 1000)   [[{{node
> CollaborativeFiltering/xusers_emb/embedding_lookup}}]]
> [Op:__inference_test_function_2209]

Any thoughts on how to resolve it? Full code and datasets are here: [Github](https://github.com/AndrewKuliahin96/ArtsRecommender).

Comment: The error message is not very informative, but appears to come from graph execution. You may get a more helpful error message if you disable graph execution by inserting a line 'tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)' before running the model. It will run much more slowly, but may give more useful info on failure. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly

Comment: The error message is incomplete, the cause is at the end of the traceback.

Comment: @DavidHarris thanks! Now error output looks like next:

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "xusers_emb" (type Embedding).

indices[28,0] = 1000 is not in [0, 1000) [Op:ResourceGather]

Call arguments received by layer "xusers_emb" (type Embedding):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(42, 1), dtype=float32)

Comment: Thanks. Dr Snoopy (comment above) had found the info was in the original error message, but I hadn't spotted it